# Python, Random vector vs Random number in an for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, for-loop, random

I am trying to solve some *stochastic differential equations*, with *Gaussian noise*. I wonder if is better to use a **Noise Vector**:

```
eta = np.random.normal(size=N)*sqrtdt
q = []
p = []
q.append(1.0)
p.append(1.0)
for i in range(N):
    q.append(f(q[i],p[i],eta[i])
    p.append(g(q[i],p[i],eta[i])
```

with *f* and *g* well behaved functions, or if I should create the **random number** in each iteration:

```
q = []
p = []
q.append(1.0)
p.append(1.0)
for i in range(N):
    eta = np.random.normal()*sqrtdt
    q.append(f(q[i],p[i],eta)
    p.append(g(q[i],p[i],eta)
```

This code should be put into another **for** loop and run for several values of **N**, which varies from 10^4 to 10^9. I am also open to another way to write this, I know **for** loops are not the closest to ***Python mindset***.

Comment: What makes you say that for-loops are not the closest to the **Python mindset**? For-loops are perfectly Pythonic.

Comment: If you are using python2, you should rather use `xrange` instead of `range` (`range(N)` will create a list of `N` numbers ...)

Comment: Well, with numpy its better to avoid for loops

Comment: I would go with the first one, idea being to do minimal work once inside a loop. I might change the way you are adding in new elems though - Might look into initialized arrays rather.

Comment: if the problem can be stated as numerical integration there are dedicated numpy, scipy functions likely better, faster than running your own backwards difference loop

Comment: The best case would be if you can use vectorized operations to compute `p` and `q` as vector functions of the array `eta`.  But we can't help you with that if we don't know what `f` and `g` do.

Comment: P.S. A simple example of a vectorized calculation of a stochastic process is shown in http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/BrownianMotion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clear-cut reply to your problem in general and assuming that "ok" performance is enough. There are actually three such strategies that I would consider here.

1. Generate all random values at the start. Pro: reduces call overhead during loop. Con: Requires a lot of memory.
2. Use an outer and an inner loop, where you generate the random values for the number of iterations of the inner loop only.
3. Do all the work in the inner loop. Pro: needs less memory. Con: Maximum call overhead.

An interesting advantage of approach "2" is that you can accelerate the inner-loop with Cython (for instance) without changing the random number generator.

You can store the current values of `q` and `p` to avoid fetching them from the list. You would append via `q.append(q_loop)` and `p.append(p_loop)`.

Anyway, if performance is a concern you should benchmark the difference strategies and consider, in a second time, the use of "acceleration" (i.e. Cython, Numba, etc). Time resolution of stochastic equations do not vectorize well, so NumPy strategies could not apply to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will take solution 2. I tried to vote your answer, but as a new user, it is not possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. (Have tried to "accept" the answer instead?)